# Is there an image file format selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I want to use the `display:none` property on all `.gif` images (displayed using `<img>` tags) on my website. Is there a CSS selector that can do that? Or is jQuery the best way to do this?

This doesn't work, but I'm looking for something like this:

```
img[gif] {
    display:none;
}
```

I know it's a simple question; Google yielded no results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```
img[src$=".gif"] { 
  display: none; 
}
```

This looks at the end of the `src` attribute for ".gif" on all `<img>` elements.